# How to infer type at key from types at other keys via function signature?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwLIEMxQLxQN5QNoDWEIAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmAumXYgEYRVQC%20A3AChQkKAGVqqdFlyFiZSrUYsK1eg16Dh0AKp0CdAPYB3OpIA8AFQB8mHISj0oREAYBmUC8rh7DJngKFwaABJOhpgADE6SwBGKAgAD2AIOgATclhESQAaDwAmeKSU9LEJNBsMAShqqAAKVyoDBDJdfWNTNFirAEpMG1bfDrBLPKtBQJEAIRoGAHl2ACszGELktIz4ZDRc0VXijPEqSQqcKpq2BHIyGEEalSorsVua%20nCyUPCo5ezRKwF-ASubwAY2ANAMdCgCBQRGmc0WZkme3WUDh8yWmxypSO5SstTO1QMYGAjwACigqGCUAAbRF-bpkJHYAlQKgQYBwKiQ5l3O4XR7YHhQFAbLLbFl3BQCoUi7E5CUvMLAMi1Wq9DA2WqC7q9WUfSLRTHbOXlbIK6oAOitRJJLJlGUmggBAmhsJm6K1LP5ZFwKDIcR4Zsl1AFUHYZAARCgI7wg4q3lAgXRQeC6PVGghejzedUGk0LSg%20FAAPTFigACwMcGpqTD0Hori4bNrwAMdagYDZ5BSwHNiYzFoSRdLFarNY7jVScGB0CbBiofbZHK5pxzOfD%20CYuRH5Er1drnAcdEbVGbUFb7bZAEc4DRm327qRN9Ud3vx52DFOZ-FT-O%20-47n8HhugCJMUwhKEYQgNFFjyRFkRKGCMTFMAdjKMArDxFkbTJCkqVpWYEHCRFcgjV5gAjTC42qciokZPAyKVCMmAEBlUVXGol05bk%2029HB7UyLZUL7KUfQEw55TXI8E1ouhqN5K0LRwu1hQdJ0AhdKCkLyT0%20UQUM-SgAN5NEnAw0jaNeH%20XIwLBCF0yaLMWTzBAC2HMtdzHA962PJsIBbNtD07CBuzoXs7hcwd3NHfcJ0-adZ1-Bc7i4lds3XMg8C3EsPLfbyjxPM8L0Pa9b3vKSnyyl9cq8uKv0SxpkpqICQKAA)

I would like to get types inferred for the `init` key in my BigObj objects created by a function. I'd like to provide the `nums` and `strs` keys and have the `init` signature have it's arguments and return type determined by `nums` and `strs`.

```js
type NumMap = { [key: string]: number };
type StrMap = { [key: string]: string };
type UnknownMap<T> = {[k in keyof T]: unknown}

type InitFn<T1 extends NumMap, T2 extends StrMap> =
    (from: UnknownMap<T1>) => UnknownMap<T2>;

type BigObj<N extends NumMap, S extends StrMap> = {
    nums: N;
    strs: S;
    init: InitFn<N,S>
}

function makeBigObj<B extends BigObj<NumMap, StrMap>>(
    opts: Partial<B>
): B {
    return {
        nums: {} as NumMap,
        strs: {} as StrMap,
        init: (() => ({})) as InitFn<NumMap, StrMap>,
        ...opts
    } as B;
}
```

But the `init` signature is not inferred properly:

```js
makeBigObj({
    nums: { a: 1 },
    strs: { b: "a" },
    init: function(from) {
        from.a; // should be inferred to be present
        from.x; // should produce error
        return {
            b: [], // should be inferred to be required
            y: []  // should produce error
        }
    }
})
```

I thought because I control the `makeBigObj` function it may infer the types better if I wrote it like this:

```js
function makeBigObj2<B extends BigObj<NumMap, StrMap>>(
    opts: Partial<Omit<B, "init">>,
    initFn: B["init"]
): B {
    return {
        nums: {} as NumMap,
        strs: {} as StrMap,
        init: initFn,
        ...opts
    } as B;
}
```

But the result is the same:

```js
makeBigObj2({
    nums: { a: 1 },
    strs: { b: "a" }
}, function(from) {
    from.a; // should be inferred to be present
    from.x; // should produce error
    return {
        b: [], // should be inferred to be required
        y: []  // should produce error
    }
})
```

How do I get `init` to be inferred to have the `a` and `b` keys and not the `x` and `y` ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two issues which cause lack of inference.

First, the `B extends BigObj<NumMap, StrMap>` generic is problematic because specifying `NumMap`/`StrMap` directly will simply use those types directly, resulting in `number`/`string` instead of inferred keys. Instead, each Map should be its own generic so that each one can be inferred independently.

```
function makeBigObj<N extends NumMap, S extends StrMap, B extends BigObj<N, S>>(
```

Secondly, for some reason having the parameter `opts: Partial<B>` refer to the `B` generic causes the compiler to expand its type to `BigObj<NumMap, StrMap>`. This can be worked around by not using the generic for the parameter but rather referring to `BigObj` directly:

```
function makeBigObj<N extends NumMap, S extends StrMap>(
    opts: Partial<BigObj<N, S>>
): BigObj<N, S> {
    return {
        nums: {} as NumMap,
        strs: {} as StrMap,
        init: (() => ({})) as InitFn<NumMap, StrMap>,
        ...opts
    } as BigObj<N, S>;
}
```

This correctly makes the line with `from.x` produce an error. The return type for `init` is also correctly inferred, but the compiler doesn't produce any errors for it. I'd guess this is because Typescript has no exact object types.